# Pentaho - move files on FTP not working

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a job that has to move a CSV file to a "processed" folder on the FTP server with date and timestamp attached to the file name.

I have the following job right now:[image]

In the "Move Files" option my source and destination addresses are of the format :

> ftp://username:password@ftp_source_address
>
> ftp://username:password@ftp_destination_address

The process succeeds till the Get a File with FTPS step and just stops after that. It works if I give a local address on my computer as the destination address.

I also tried the "Copy or move result file names" action and it behaves exactly the same way. What am I missing here?

I am new to pentaho and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `Get a File with FTPS` job entry works by pulling a file from a remote server to the local server that is running Pentaho. It doesn't move a file on a remote server to a different location on a remote server. The `Move Files` job entry is likely failing (or simply doing nothing) because the file is not where you're expecting it to be due to the `Get a File with FTPS` job entry not functioning the way it seems you're expecting it to.

Based on the design you've shown in the attached image, I think you could completely remove the `Get a File with FTPS` and just use the `Move Files` job entry.

Comment: Well, my requirement is to pull a file to the local server that is running pentaho and  then move that file to another folder on the FTP. So I guess I would need `Get a File with FTPS`

Answer (score 0):

The Get files via FTPS step has a built in move after retrieval function that will work for all the files download through it.

[image]

In the Move to folder variable area, you insert your desired FTPS path, e.g \source\backup\${variables}.
This field accepts variables so you can even dynamically create backup folders if you check the Create folder option as well.

Comment: I need to add a timestamp to the file name. So this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of similiar requirement and resolved it, let me state it first:

*I need to create a csv file in Local server (ETL server) and send back to Remote server location. But before doing it I need to archive the already existing file into a seperate (Archived) folder in the Remote server.*

I used all possible ways to resolve but go it done by the job as defined below:

**Step 1** : Get the old file from the remote to local using 'Get a file with FTP'. In the same step definition I remove the old file once it is transferred.

**Step 2** : Used 'Put a file with FTP' to do the reverse in the folder named 'Archived' in the remote server, and same way removed the file from the local server

**Step 3** : Created a Transformation to do the rest work to create a csv file and place it to Local server.

Thus, the previous old file is moved and stored in 'Archived' folder and the new file generated from the Transformation. It has the timestamp insertion process also, so it might cater the need. Hope this helps !!!

Below is the job and how it looks:
[Pentaho JOB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIMYm.png)